Quale traduzione dall'inglese "success" in un contesto informatico?
Siamo abituati nei programmi o nei siti, quando ad esempio salviamo qualcosa a ricevere l'esito della operazione con (almeno) due termini inglesi:

success!
failed!

Il secondo è facilmente traducibile in italiano con "fallito" e dal contesto si evince chiaramente il significato: passato del verbo fallire e non sostantivo.
Ho più difficoltà con il primo: "successo" non ha molto senso in italiano. In alcuni casi andrebbe bene "completato (con successo)" ma non sempre è adeguato.
In quale altro modo si potrebbe tradurre, mantenendo il senso generico di "esito positivo" e da utilizzarsi come parola autonoma, non inserita in una frase?
Esempio:
https://codepen.io/warrendunlop/pen/YmVKzm


Se devo essere sincero, non ho capito bene neppure l'uso di “fallito” qui. Forse mi manca il contesto, anche perché “fallito” può significare tante cose. A cosa si riferisce “fallito” qui? Non può essere “operazione” perché è femminile. O è il programma che dice “(ho) fallito”? Anche questo però non suona molto idiomatico.

@DaG si, esatto. Avevo in mente "salvataggio" > "fallito", oppure nel caso di "operazione" > "fallita". Concordo sul fatto che la prima persona non sia adeguata.

@DaG ho aggiunto un esempio alla domanda per chiarire un eventuale uso. Non è specifico, solo per esemplificare un caso d'uso

Il problema è che l'italiano non ha parole abbastanza generiche come l'inglese, che invece permette di poter scrivere "Success" o "Failed" in quasi ogni contesto.
Comunque se vuoi essere abbastanza generico, prendi in considerazione queste opzioni (anche se non sempre vanno bene):

Operazione completata
Operazione fallita
Fatto
Errore

Altrimenti puoi specificare cosa è andato bene o storto:

Login eseguito
Logout fallito
Salvataggio completato
Eliminazione effettuata

